# Retornar id(primary key) cuando creo el registro desce c# NET CORE 6

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

Es un poco complicado de explicar, necesito guardar un registro con algunos datos, lo cual lo hago desde C# Linq con este codigo:

```
public class ProductService : IProductService
    {
        public bool InsertProduct(InsertProductModel model, MQMContext db)
        {
            var user = db.Usuarios.Where(el => el.IdUsuario == model.UserId).FirstOrDefault();

            if (user == null)
                return false;

            Producto newProduct = new Producto();
            newProduct.IdUsuario = model.UserId;
            newProduct.Nombre = "Mi Producto";

            db.Productos.AddRange(newProduct);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return true;
        }
    }
```

Hasta aqui todo bien, se guarda el registro y a dicho registro se le genera un id (idProducto) autoincrementable en el propio Sql, lo que necesito es poder reenviar ese id que genera devuelta a c#.

Existe alguna manera de hacer eso??, no encontre mucho, pero lei algo de executeScalar que segun lo que lei hace esto: "El método ExecuteScalar se utiliza para devolver el valor de columna de identidad para el registro insertado". No entiendo bien que seria la columna de identidad. Agradeceria alguna orientacion

Comment: Haz probado con en lugar de retornar true o false, retornar Producto?

Comment: @Julito Maraña, evidentemente no entiendes lo que pido. Lo que necesito es que sql me retorne el id (que es la clave primaria) del registro que acabo de crear

Comment: Evidentemente no haz provado a retornar el objeto, pruebalo o solamente retorna ell product.id

Comment: @Julito Maraña, tenias razon, si funciona!!, fui un poco duro con mi respuesta, disculpa y muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al momento de guardar un dato en tu base automaticamente se guarda tu id en el objeto.
Al retornar `newProduct` que acabas de guardar, automáticamente se guarda el valor del ID con el que se guarda en la base de datos, en caso de que tengas un campo donde guardes ese valor en `newProduct`.

Si no deseas como tal retornar todo el objeto `newProduct`, lo que puedes hacer es:

```
return newProduct.IdUsuario;
```

Y en vez de retornar un `bool`, retorna un `int`.

Comment: muchas gracias!!